# Does texting internationally use data?

Tags: iphone

I have been texting a friend in Mexico for several months. One of my friends was alarmed and said I was using my data. Is that true?

Comment: In what app are you texting and is he message delivered as green (SMS) or blue (iMessage)?

Comment: I think you'd probably have noticed on your phone bill by now. Not sure where you live but in the UK old-style SMS text [green] costs about £0.50 each to send abroad. An iMessage [blue] costs nothing so long as you have enough data allowance left, or are sending over WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

you always use data to text using imessage, although if you have it set to text message. it will not 
( as seen in picture )

[image]